# Adding a column to designate column observations in sportsreference scrape

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[Marko Prcać]provided the following answer to ([Sportsipy API request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67082305/sportsipy-api-request))

```
from sportsreference.nba.schedule import Schedule

# MIL removed from league list as it is used to initiate league_schedule
league = ['CHO','LAL','LAC','SAC','ATL','MIA','DAL','POR',
          'HOU','NOP','PHO','WAS','MEM','BOS','DEN','TOR','SAS',
          'PHI','BRK','UTA','IND','OKC','ORL','MIN','DET',
          'NYK','CLE','CHI','GSW']

league_schedule = Schedule('MIL', year="2020").dataframe
for team in league:
     league_schedule = league_schedule.append(Schedule(team , year="2020").dataframe)
```

This works perfectly for my needs - the dataframe returned yields all the relevant information except the league team itself. One gets the game_time, etc but not the team the schedule is for. The result is:

```
    boxscore_index               date   datetime  ...               streak   time  wins
    201910240HOU   201910240HOU  Thu, Oct 24, 2019 2019-10-24  ...     W 1  8:00p     1
    201910260MIL   201910260MIL  Sat, Oct 26, 2019 2019-10-26  ...     L 1  5:00p     1
    201910280MIL   201910280MIL  Mon, Oct 28, 2019 2019-10-28  ...     W 1  8:00p     2
    201910300BOS   201910300BOS  Wed, Oct 30, 2019 2019-10-30  ...     L 1  7:30p     2
    201911010ORL   201911010ORL  Fri, Nov 1, 2019  2019-11-01  ...     W 1  7:00p     3
```

But what I want is an additional column that states MIL for all column observations associated with MIL, CHO for all column observations associated with CHO, etc.. The resulting DataFrame would look like this

```
    boxscore_index               team      date      datetime  ...        streak   time  wins
    201910240HOU   201910240HOU  MIL  Thu, Oct 24, 2019 2019-10-24  ...     W 1  8:00p     1
    201910260MIL   201910260MIL  MIL  Sat, Oct 26, 2019 2019-10-26  ...     L 1  5:00p     1
    201910280MIL   201910280MIL  MIL  Mon, Oct 28, 2019 2019-10-28  ...     W 1  8:00p     2
    201910300BOS   201910300BOS  MIL  Wed, Oct 30, 2019 2019-10-30  ...     L 1  7:30p     2
    201911010ORL   201911010ORL  MIL  Fri, Nov 1, 2019  2019-11-01  ...     W 1  7:00p     3
```

Comment: Without access to your whole dataframe, how do I know from your given examples which team to match with which row? Why in your example output for the first line is not the team "HOU" instead of 'MIL'?

Comment: The boxscore is designated by the home team - so half will be MIL and the other half will be the teams they play on the road. The dataFrame is populated by downloading the MIL games and stacking them on top of the CHO game, the LAL games, etc...  Yes the difficulty is that once the DataFrame is created it is very difficult to designate which of the observations associate with which of the teams. That's why I need to figure out how to populate the team column as it's populating the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little more work and a little help this is will work:

```
from sportsreference.nba.schedule import Schedule
import pandas as pd

league = ['MIL','CHO','LAL','LAC','SAC','ATL','MIA','DAL',
          'POR','HOU','NOP','PHO','WAS','MEM','BOS','DEN',
          'TOR','SAS','PHI','BRK','UTA','IND','OKC','ORL',
          'MIN','DET','NYK','CLE','CHI','GSW']

df = pd.DataFrame([])

for team in league:
   df_ = Schedule(team, year='2020').dataframe
   df_['team'] = team
   df = df.append(df_)
```

This will yield:

```
                  boxscore_index      date           datetime  ...    time  wins team
     201910240HOU   201910240HOU  Thu, Oct 24, 2019 2019-10-24  ...  8:00p    1   MIL
     201910260MIL   201910260MIL  Sat, Oct 26, 2019 2019-10-26  ...  5:00p    1   MIL
     201910280MIL   201910280MIL  Mon, Oct 28, 2019 2019-10-28  ...  8:00p    2   MIL
     201910300BOS   201910300BOS  Wed, Oct 30, 2019 2019-10-30  ...  7:30p    2   MIL
     201911010ORL   201911010ORL   Fri, Nov 1, 2019 2019-11-01  ...  7:00p    3   MIL
```